# Получить item из ListView при нажатии на картинку в этом item'е

Tags: android

Здравствуйте.

Пишу приложение под Android. Есть у меня список(ListView).
В каждом item'е этого списка есть картинка. Эта картинка кликабельна. Так же в этом item'е есть несколько TextView.

Вопрос:
Как я могу получить значение TextView, которое находится в том item'е, в котором пользователь нажал на картинку.

Если бы пользователь нажимал на весь item то можно было бы сделать как-то так.

```
TextView tview = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1); //v - это элемент View, который передается в Listener при вызове
```

Затем было бы достаточно сделать

```
tview.getText()
```

и всё.

Но в моем случает пользователь нажимает на картинку и не понятно, как узнать в каком item'е находится эта картинка.

Не могли бы вы мне помочь.

P.S.
 1. Простите за непонятный заголовок вопроса. :)
 2. Даже не знаю как этот вопрос гуглу скормить.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

В методе **getView()** адаптера назначал бы тег для картинки (к примеру **setTag(position)**), где **position** - текущий индекс элемента списка.

Потом при клике по картинке в колбэке брал бы этот индекс методом **getTag()** и вуаля: мы знаем индекс элемента **ListView**, в котором была нажата картинка.

И если есть возможность хранить тексты для всех **TextView** в массиве, то по этому индексу я бы получил искомый текст.