# Как получить позицию listVIew?

Tags: android, java

Как получить позицию нажатия по `listVIew` компонента?

То есть не самого `listView`, а того `View`, который в нем, допустим, text и image. Вот если нажали на image, как мне узнать позицию строчки из списка `listView` - 3 там 6 или 12?

Что-то типа `listview.getPosition` не нашел.

Есть

```
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)   {
        }
    });
```

Но это если нажать на саму строчку в `listView`, а мне так не надо.

Answer (score 3):

Всё просто. Вешайте слушателей кликов в методе

> getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

адаптера списка на нужный элемент.

В этом методе адаптера есть **position**. Именно он вам и нужен.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а почему нельзя так сделать?

     listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                switch (view.getId()){
                    case R.id.img:
                       Тут указываем на View который в listVIew?
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, getView в адаптере, он рисует, надо не адаптер проверять а сам listView...
Так что вы неправы.

Там в другом методе надо

Comment: @Futurama, способ, предлагаемый вами, вешает слушатель на весь элемент списка (со всеми его детьми). Вы же, насколько я понял, хотите именно на ребёнка элемента списка повесить слушатель, а не на весь элемент.

Answer (score 1):

[Подобный вопрос уже задавался на форуме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/180687/android-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-item-%D0%B8%D0%B7-listview-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-item-%D0%B5)